# Declare a variable with type of other type's variable type

Tags: javascript, typescript

The title looks complex. Let me try to open the topic. Have a look at a type used:

```js
export interface IUser {
  id: string;
  displayName: string;
  email?: string;
  imageUrl?: string;
  disabled?: boolean;
  since?: Date;
}
```

There is a piece of the code where I need to declare a new variable - `id`.
I expect this variable to be the type to be the same that `IUser` has as its `id`. In this case it would be `string`, but if the `IUser` is changed, I'd rather not change the variable type manually, but use something like:

`let id:typeOf(IUser.id)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use square brackets to define type.

```
export interface IUser_1 {
  id: string;
}

const id_1: IUser_1['id'] = 'foo';

export interface IUser_2 {
  id: number;
}

const id_2: IUser_2['id'] = 7;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use square bracket notation:

```js
const id:IUser['id'] = '#1'
```

In this case, if you change the type of `id` in the interface, type of `id` variable will be also changed.